# Disable `mixed content` blocking in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, https

A friend asked me to build a simple Microsoft Word add-in for him, which calls a HTTP API. I am on Linux with no access to Microsoft Office, so I thought I use the browser version to test my add-in. This works so far, but all my browsers block the access to the HTTP API, since the Word page was loaded over HTTPS (something long the lines of `mixed content warning`). I googled for options to disable this (like clicking the "shield" symbol next to the URL and then allow mixed content), but there was no "allow" button or anything.

Is there anything I can do in Firefox or Chrome to temporarily allow mixed content?

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).

Comment: I agree it is not a MS Word question, so I have removed that tag. But since it is an issue related to testing my code, I would argue it is a programming question in some sense.